# Swift: How do you get the velocity for each touches with UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I would like to get the velocity for each touches using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` like what you can do with the location of the touches using the method `location(ofTouch: Int, in: UIView)`. However, when I use the method `velocity(in: view)`, it only returns one of the velocities of the touches. I tried changing the `maximumNumberOfTouches` property but it didn't work.

Is there any way you can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved this by creating a 2d array of `CGPoint` called `touchLocations` and another array of `CGPoint` called `touchVelocities`. In a for loop looping through all the touches, I added

```
if !touchLocations.indices.contains(touchNumber) {
    touchLocations.append([CGPoint]())
}
touchLocations[touchNumber].append(sender.location(ofTouch: touchNumber, in: view))
```

to assign a new `CGPoint` for each touches (`touchNumber` is the index of the touch and `sender` is the gesture recognizer).

Then I added

```
touchLocations[touchNumber] = touchLocations[touchNumber].suffix(2)
```

So that the array only contains the last 2 elements.

To get the velocity, I simply did

```
touchVelocities.insert(CGPoint(x: touchLocations[touchNumber].last!.x - touchLocations[touchNumber].first!.x, y: touchLocations[touchNumber].last!.y - touchLocations[touchNumber].first!.y), at: touchNumber)
```

(Subtracted the first x value from the second x value for the x velocity, and did the same thing for the y velocity)

I know this method is not very accurate, however it was good enough for my purposes.